# Cannot build CloudHopper (SMPP)

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, smpp

I have downloaded the source from github from this link: https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp however when I try to build this in Netbeans I am getting two errors, as follows:

1) Right at the start of build in the output window it says:

```
Scanning for projects...

Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for     com.cloudhopper:ch-smpp:jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT
The expression ${scm.url} is deprecated. Please use ${project.scm.url} instead.

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of     your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed     projects.
```

2) At the end of the build the output window says:

```
Results :

Failed tests:       serverBindToUnavailablePortThrowsException(com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppServerTest)

Tests run: 162, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 27.606s
Finished at: Sun Mar 10 09:42:27 GMT 2013
Final Memory: 21M/314M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test     (default-test) on project ch-smpp: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\CloudHopper\cloudhopper-smpp-master\cloudhopper-    smpp-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the     following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I would like to be able to build the required jar files and run the demos provided.

Any ideas how to get this building properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `test` folder in `src/` and try building with Netbeans. It will compile the jar properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the project using maven in order to get the jar file.

[This is the link for Cloudhopper-jar file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtrge3mazlr3feg/ch-smpp-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar)

Comment: thanks for the link. I have all the jar files also. though I was wanting to get the source building properly locally too. How can I resolve the issue above? How do I execute the project using maven? will this resolve my issue above?